# Pause an ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a lot of data to process and insert into a list, then I need to insert this list into my DB everytime it have 100k Strings inside. How can I pause the ExecutorService while I save the list to DB?
Can I lock it?

example code with my problem:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadAmount);
List <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object obj: ObjectList){
  objectThreadProcess dto = new ObjectThreadProcess(obj.toString(), obj.id);
  executor.submit(dto);
  executor.execute(dto);
  if(list.size() == 100000){
    //I need to pause threads here to not insert while I'm inserting into DB and creating a new list
    ObjDAO.largeInsert(list);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
  }
}
```

Comment: `executor.submit(dto); executor.execute(dto);`  - why do you submit the task twice?

Comment: It's an example code, It wasn't planned, but thanks for this observation

Comment: nope, largeInsert is a method in ObjDAO (which is a static class) where I get this list and will insert on DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you need not to pause the ExecutorService. What you need is to block the threads which try to write to the list, and not to pause the thread pool. Or else one day you place the task which writes to database in that threadpool, it pauses the thread pool including itself, and the whole process hangs.

You can simply make 2 synchronized methods - one to write to the list and one to read from it, push to database and clear it. You need them in any case, since the list is accessed from different threads.